Installing tidyverse package fails
In an R session in a macOS terminal window, I'm trying to install tidyverse:

install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")

(or any other shorter version of this command).
Regardless of what I try, the result is this:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘haven’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library/00LOCK-haven/00new/haven/libs/haven.so':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library/00LOCK-haven/00new/haven/libs/haven.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_libiconv'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library/haven’
ERROR: dependency ‘haven’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library/tidyverse’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/zk/h_ph45q52m571my3gjkycyx80000gn/T/RtmpqtCJg7/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",  :
  installation of package ‘haven’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",  :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

Session info:
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
...

I had been unsuccessfully trying to install tidyverse in RStudio (Version 2024.04.2+764 (2024.04.2+764), so I resorted to an R session in a Terminal.app window.
I tried this (uninstalling rlang, tidyselect; reinstalling them and then installing tidyverse) and this (deleting .Rhistory, .Rdata, and .Rprofile files, restarting R) without success.
Any tried and true workarounds for this problem?

Is there a particular reason why you are using type = "source"? If so, you must make sure that all system dependencies are available (here: libiconv). And on the off-chance that you are using Conda: you cannot mix Conda with install.packages() from inside R.

As I mentioned, I had used all forms of install.packages(), meaning with and without all the extra parameters. So, that includes install.packages("tidyverse") and install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE), and one with the repos param. And, I'm not using conda.

Well, the /opt/homebrew/ part of the error indicates that you may have installed R from homebrew rather than the official R website. The homebrew versions ofter has issues when linking against shared objects when installing package. I believe it's possible to install R packages via homebrew as well, but things would probably be much easier if you used the officially supported R installer. install.packages() will probably work fine in that case.

What @MrFlick said is spot-on: don’t install R via Homebrew. But if you absolutely insists, use brew install --cask (https://fosstodon.org/@jennybryan/113127136040394821).

@MrFlick: Installing R from the official R website solved the problem. Thanks
